# Is the expectation of the sample conditional log-likelihhod a conditional expectation?

Tags: conditional-expectation, maximum-likelihood

I have a doubt related to the MLE theory. Suppose we have a sample of i.i.d. real valued random variables $(Y_i, X_i)_{i=1}^n$ with $Y_i=X_i\beta+u_i$, $\beta\in B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $u_i|X_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, $0<\sigma^2<\infty$. Then the sample log-likelihood function of $Y_i$ conditional on $X_i$ is 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(f(Y_i|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2))=-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{n}{2}\log(\sigma^2)-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-X_i\beta)^2}{2\sigma^2}
$$

by the LLN we can write that 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(f(Y_i|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)) \rightarrow_p E(\log(f(Y_i|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)))
$$

Question: what is exactly $E(\log(f(Y_i|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)))$? Is it computed using the distribution of $Y_i$ conditional on $X_i$ or the joint distribution of $Y_i,X_i$?

Comment: 1. No expression $$\log(f(Y_i)|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)$$ is making any sense. 2. One knows that $$E(\log(f(Y_i))\mid X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)=u(X_i,\beta,\sigma^2)$$ where the function $u$ is defined as $$u(x,b,s^2)=E(\log f(bx+sZ))$$ for some standard normal random variable $Z$.

Comment: After the modification of the post, note that $\log f(Y_i|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)$ is at least as absurd as $\log(f(Y_i)|X_i;\beta, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: Can I ask you more explanation? What I mean is the conditional pdf of $Y_i$.

Comment: "More explanation" is that there is no definition for $E(f(U\mid V))$ since the object $(U\mid V)$ does not exist. On the other hand, $E(f(U)\mid V)$ is a random variable with a solid definition and, if $U$ has conditional PDF $g(\ \mid v)$ conditionally on $V=v$, then $E(f(U)\mid V)=h(V)$ with $h(v)=\int f(u)g(u\mid v)du$.